# d-d transitions in materials with transition metals in DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, transition-metals, dft-u

While reading the literature on the absorption spectra of materials from the MPX3 group (M= Mn,Ni,Co, Fe; layered antiferromagnets) I come across expressions such as d-d transitions, which are visible as weak transitions before the absorption edge ([example DOI](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.44.11060)). These formulations and designations, as I understand it, come from the molecular theories of the crystal field. I calculated (DFT+U) the density of states for such materials and I do not see separated bands in the electronic structure composed of only d-states (which is not surprising), only bands that, for example, consist of half of the p-ligand states and the d-states of the transition metal.
Nowadays, in the literature on these crystalline materials, such peaks in the spectra are called d-d transitions that lie in the energy gap.

What are these d-d transitions in a pure crystal?
Can they be captured with DFT?
In addition to the electronic structure of the crystal, do I need to consider any internal atomic levels of the transition metal itself in this case?

Comment: In molecules, d-d transitions can be computed by TDDFT, but they are generally inaccurate, and multireference methods are generally necessary. I guess in crystals the situation is even worse (for example the self-interaction error of density functionals is more pronounced), but I don't have experience on this